# prometheus `kube_node_status_condition merged * kube_node_status_condition` returns many nodes

Tags: prometheus, promql

Using the following prometheus images inside EKS 1.22:

```
alertmanager:v0.23.0
kube-state-metrics:v2.4.1
prometheus/node-exporter:v1.3.0
prometheus:v2.34.0
```

I'm trying to get labels of the node that is in NotReady condition. However when this alarm fires I get a slack notification with ALL nodes in the cluster. However only a single node is marked as `NotReady`

```bash
kubectl get nodes
NAME                           STATUS      ROLES    AGE     VERSION
ip-10-110-0-102.ec2.internal   NotReady    <none>   17h     v1.22.9-eks-810597c
ip-10-110-1-79.ec2.internal    Ready       <none>   2d16h   v1.22.9-eks-810597c
ip-10-110-3-243.ec2.internal   Ready       <none>   2d16h   v1.22.9-eks-810597c
ip-10-110-4-137.ec2.internal   Ready       <none>   2d14h   v1.22.9-eks-810597c
...
```

**the alert rule:**

```
(kube_node_status_condition{condition="Ready",status=~"unknown|false"} == 1) 
  * on(node) group_right() kube_node_labels
```

**Slack notification shows many entries:**

[image]